# Simplify column selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sub that, following a user selection of a range (a series of dates with additional data), checks through a second range (a calendar) and if it finds a match, copies the entry from the original selection to the calendar.

I was having some issues with the formatting, particularly shading, so I opted to just clear the shading from each individual cell in the copied range.

My question is - can the `Interior.ColourIndex` entries be simplified so that I can do them all at once?

Thank you for your time.

```
Sub Test()
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim Assessment As Range
Dim RangeString As String
Dim InsertRow As Long


RangeString = Selection.Address
Set MyRange = Range(RangeString)

For Each Assessment In MyRange.Rows
    For Each Cell In Range("$B$2:$B$150").Columns(1).Cells
        If Cell.Value = Assessment.Columns(1).Cells.Value Then
        InsertRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(InsertRow).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        Assessment.Rows.Copy
        Cells(InsertRow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Cells(InsertRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Cells(InsertRow, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Cells(InsertRow, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Cells(InsertRow, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Cells(InsertRow, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Cells(InsertRow, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit For
        
        End If
                    
    Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set MyRange = Selection` (no need for RangeString).`Cells(InsertRow, 3).Resize(, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`. But there are probably issues with the copying (it should be done from the bottom to the top). Could you post some sample data or some screenshots?

Comment: Both of your contributions worked and answered the question I had.